# Gnucash fee option

Tags: gnucash

My problem is that I can't handle translations with fees using gnucash. 
For example, I have an account that represents my bank account. 
I'd like to withdrawal $100 and my bank will also charge me for $2.6. So the sum to descries is $102.6.
Here is my split transaction with fees:

[image]

So,

1. Increase cash in a wallet
2. Decrease cash on my bank my bank account
3. Also decrease the same account ($2.6 fee)
4. Got `Imbalance-USD`

So does the column action does not work and I should also create an account for all charges or I do something in a wrong way?

Thanks.

UDP: 
So i removed Imbalance via a new account:

[image]

I'm not sure that it is right solution, but ... probably it's okay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Typically you start with the asset being withdrawn from - in this case I'd start with your bank account you made the withdrawal from - let's call it Assets:CurrentAssets:Checking.

In the Assets:CurrentAssets:Checking ledger, list the total withdrawal, including the fee in a split as follows:

```
Assets:CurrentAssets:Checking: decrease 102.60
    Assets:CurrentAssets:Cash: increase 100.00
    Expenses:Bank Service Charge: increase 2.60
```

That should be all that is required....  good luck.

Edit: you might get an `Imbalance` amount temporarily as you enter the split.  You can either change that category to `Bank Service Charge` or delete it after you enter the 'Bank Service Charge' on a separate line in the split.  Either way, it'll balance after that.